# Does a motherboard with socket 775 support Core 2 Duo CPUs?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, processor-socket

I have a D102ggc2 motherboard  with socket 775 and my neighbour has a Biostar socket 775 motherboard.

He has a Core 2 Duo processor with 2.93 GHz and I have a Pentium 4 with 3.06 GHz. I wanted to change my processor and I checked the Intel website – but for my motherboard, the only supported processors were Celeron, Pentium D and Pentium 4.

**How come socket 775 supports Core 2 Duo?**

If I upgraded my processor to a Core 2 Duo, would it cause any problems with my DDR2 RAM, motherboard or any other component of my PC?

Comment: Core 2 required a voltage regulator on the motherboard that was not needed for the Pentium D line of processors, some early 775 socket motherboards do not have this VR, which includes your Intel mobo, so no it will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core 2 required a voltage regulator on the motherboard that was not needed for the Pentium D line of processors, all early 775 socket motherboards do not have this VR, which includes your Intel mobo, so no it will not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is **No, your motherboard does not support Core 2 Duo.**

Long answer is that since Intel used this socket for a long time, you'll have to check with what your motherboard says it supports. Newer motherboards with the same socket, came out around the time the newer CPU's with the same socket arrived.

From [CPU World](http://www.cpu-world.com/Sockets/Socket%20775%20%28LGA775%29.html):

> All LGA775 CPU's will physically fit into the socket LGA775, but not all of them are supported by all motherboards. If you're upgrading an old computer system please make sure that the CPU is compatible with your motherboard.

Comment: @Tilman  : Need a little more detailed explanation. Thanks

Comment: @FrozenKing There's not much to explain, your motherboard hardware has to support the CPU. The newer LGA755's have different voltages and clock speeds that aren't supported.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed duo core processors up to 2.6 GHz 800 MHz FSB on these older M.B. . I was told by everyone they would not work but I installed on a lark and they worked and performed perfectly. In dells and Some HP s . HP bios seemed to limit success on some. But I have installed 2 core duo processors on M.B. s with the orig bios and in spite of everything I was told on the support sites. They worked fine. this surprised  me I have only run across a few HP s that the duo core did not work on ! The MB s would support up to 800 MHz 2.6 90% of the time. Above that not so much in the real old desktops. With LGA 775 socket.