# CPU, Motherboard, BIOS compatibility

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, compatibility, intel-core2

I have a fairly old desktop, currently with an ABIT AL8-V motherboard, which I had had running with a Pentium D 930+ (3.0ghz dual core). I purchased and installed a core 2 quad (also socket 755), [Q6600 SLACR](http://ark.intel.com/products/29765). Now, my motherboard recognizes it, but the BIOS chip in my motherboard does not. The motherboard code ([link to manual](http://db.tt/Aedm3iti)) reads 9.0. (different from 90), which means that the board has completed it's checks and is switching to the AWARD BIOS (actually Phoneix-made BIOS). If I can get a new BIOS chip (the 7-pin-by-9-pin kind) which supports the Core 2 Quad, will this motherboard work with this processor? Can I, in fact, switch BIOS chips without my motherboard stopping working? Is there any way besides finding a new motherboard to use my Core 2 Quad? If I need a new board, will an ASUS P5RDM-V2 work? (yes, that's a smaller board, but I have another computer with the Pentium D 930+ and that board adn woudl use it.)

[This may be a helpful reference, but I'm not sure about my motherboard. I don't see the chip on either the AL8-V or the P5RDM-V2, but I'm not very good at identifying them.](https://superuser.com/questions/483540/does-a-motherboard-with-socket-775-support-core-2-duo-cpus)

Comment: If the motherboard supports the CPU but the BIOS does not, put the old CPU back in and upgrade the BIOS. The chip can be reprogrammed, you don't need a new physical chip. (You should have confirmed you had the right BIOS version before changing CPUs, but we've all made this mistake.) In any event, see my answer. Your board can't support Core 2 CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AL8-V [cannot support](http://abit.ws/cpu-support-list/mb/intel_945p_al8_series.htm) any Core 2 CPUs.

Comment: Well, thanks for finding this. Any data on the P5RDM-V2?

Comment: Also, do you have any board recommendations for DDR2 Socket 755 boards which would support a Core 2 Quad?

Comment: (Yes, I know to mark your answer as correct, but I want to see if I can get an answer on the ASUS board.)

Comment: Do you mean the P5RD2-VM? I don't think there is a `P5RDM-V2`. If so, [no](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5RD2VM/#CPUS). Sorry.

Comment: That's what I meant. Thanks. I don't have that board handy. Oh well, I'll just get a new board at some point.

Comment: If you ask in the right place, you can probably get a mobo for free or the cost of shipping. I just recently threw out several socket 775 mobo's that had dual-core Core2 CPUs in them (not worth the power any more and I didn't have extra Q9xxx series CPUs), but I'm sure there are people who keep obsolete equipment longer than I do. (I see them on eBay for $10 or less.)

Comment: Do you know if this would work? http://www.amazon.com/Atx-Express-UDMA133-ATA-300-Gigabit/dp/B000GS2QX0/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=25MBIPB92HG5U&coliid=I17D32WL2EKXSP

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a new BIOS **chip**. When people say 'you need a new BIOS' they mean you need to program (flash) a new BIOS program in your BIOS chip.

To solve your problem you want to:

- Go to the motherboards mnufacturers website.
- Check if they have a new BIOS file which supports your new CPU
- Flash the BIOS (use the old CPU to do that)
- Only then you change to the new CPU.

Comment: I know the difference between the BIOS chip and BIOS software on that chip; ABit has gone out of business and no longer has a website to check, I believe.